# Apache2 and PHPJAVA Bridge

Tags: java, php, apache, php-java-bridge

I am trying to get PHPJAVA bridge to work on my present Apache2 setup.

Although, frankly, I have no idea where to start.

I have downloaded the JavaBridgeTemplate621.war and do not know where to put it.

Appreciate any help. Did not find the docs clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure you should put in the webapps directory for apache **tomcat**. 
I think you'll need to install tomcat unless your sure you can run .war files on apache2.
If you can then put the JavaBridgeTemplate621.war in a similar directory. 
I totally understand by what you mean with the docs being unclear, I still have know idea why anything I do works :(.